# Conditional coloring of cells in table

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I am trying to create a data table whose cells are different colors based on the value in the cell. I can achieve this with the function `addtable2plot` from the `plotrix` package. The `addtable2plot` function lays a table on an already existing plot. The problem with that solution is that I don't want a plot, just the table.

I've also looked at the `heatmap` functions. The problem there is that some of the values in my table are character, and the `heatmap` functions, from what I can tell, only accept numeric matrices. Also, I want my column names to be at the top of the table, not the bottom, and that doesn't seem to be an option.

Here's the example code for `addtable2plot`. If I could get just the table, filling the whole screen, that would be great.

```
library(plotrix)

testdf<-data.frame(Before=c(10,7,5,9),During=c(8,6,2,5),After=c(5,3,4,3))
rownames(testdf)<-c("Red","Green","Blue","Lightblue")
barp(testdf,main="Test addtable2plot",ylab="Value",
     names.arg=colnames(testdf),col=2:5)
# show most of the options including the christmas tree colors
abg<-matrix(c(2,3,5,6,7,8),nrow=4,ncol=3)
addtable2plot(2,8,testdf,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlines=TRUE,
              vlines=TRUE,title="The table",bg=abg)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you start by initializing a blank plot? `plot(0,type="n",bty="n",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ylab="",xlab="")`

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323885/how-to-color-specific-cells-in-a-data-frame-table-in-r

Answer (score 19):

### **A `heatmap` alternative:**

```
library(gplots)

# need data as matrix
mm <- as.matrix(testdf, ncol = 3)

heatmap.2(x = mm, Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none",
          cellnote = mm, notecol = "black", notecex = 2,
          trace = "none", key = FALSE, margins = c(7, 11))
```

In `heatmap.2` the side of the plot the `axis` is to be drawn on is hard-coded. But if you type "`heatmap.2`" at the console and copy the output to an editor, you can search for `axis(1`, where the 1 is the `side` argument (two hits). You can then change from a 1 (axis below plot) to a 3 (axis above the plot). Assign the updated function to a new name, e.g. heatmap.3, and run it as above.

[image]

---

### **An `addtable2plot` alternative**

```
library(plotrix)

# while plotrix is loaded anyway:
# set colors with color.scale
# need data as matrix*
mm <- as.matrix(testdf, ncol = 3)
cols <- color.scale(mm, extremes = c("red", "yellow"))

par(mar = c(0.5, 1, 2, 0.5))
# create empty plot
plot(1:10, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "n")

# add table
addtable2plot(x = 1, y = 1, table = testdf,
              bty = "o", display.rownames = TRUE,
              hlines = TRUE, vlines = TRUE,
              bg = cols,
              xjust = 2, yjust = 1, cex = 3)

# *According to `?color.scale`, `x` can be a data frame.
# However, when I tried with `testdf`, I got "Error in `[.data.frame`(x, segindex) : undefined columns selected".
```

[image]

---

### **A `color2D.matplot` alternative**

```
library(plotrix)
par(mar = c(0.5, 8, 3.5, 0.5))
color2D.matplot(testdf, 
                show.values = TRUE,
                axes = FALSE,
                xlab = "",
                ylab = "",
                vcex = 2,
                vcol = "black",
                extremes = c("red", "yellow"))
axis(3, at = seq_len(ncol(testdf)) - 0.5,
     labels = names(testdf), tick = FALSE, cex.axis = 2)
axis(2, at = seq_len(nrow(testdf)) -0.5,
     labels = rev(rownames(testdf)), tick = FALSE, las = 1, cex.axis = 2)
```

[image]

After this little exercise, I tend to agree with @Drew Steen that LaTeX alternatives may be investigated as well. For example, check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz?lq=1).

Answer (score 9):

You can hack something with grid and gtable,

```
palette(c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Pastel1"),
          RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Pastel2")))


library(gtable)
gtable_add_grobs <- gtable_add_grob # alias

d <- head(iris, 3)
nc <- ncol(d)
nr <- nrow(d)

extended_matrix <- cbind(c("", rownames(d)), rbind(colnames(d), as.matrix(d))) 

## text for each cell
all_grobs <- matrix(lapply(extended_matrix, textGrob), ncol=ncol(d) + 1)

## define the fill background of cells
fill <- lapply(seq_len(nc*nr), function(ii) 
  rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=ii)))

## some calculations of cell sizes
row_heights <- function(m){
  do.call(unit.c, apply(m, 1, function(l)
    max(do.call(unit.c, lapply(l, grobHeight)))))
}

col_widths <- function(m){
  do.call(unit.c, apply(m, 2, function(l)
    max(do.call(unit.c, lapply(l, grobWidth)))))
}

## place labels in a gtable
g <- gtable_matrix("table", grobs=all_grobs, 
                   widths=col_widths(all_grobs) + unit(4,"mm"), 
                   heights=row_heights(all_grobs) + unit(4,"mm"))

## add the background
g <- gtable_add_grobs(g, fill, t=rep(seq(2, nr+1), each=nc), 
                      l=rep(seq(2, nc+1), nr), z=0,name="fill")

## draw
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Sort of a hacky solution based on `ggplot2`. I don't totally understand how you actually want to map your colors, since in your example the colors in the table are not mapped to the rownames of `testdf`, but here I've mapped the colors to the `value` (converted to a factor).

```
testdf$color <- rownames(testdf)
dfm <- melt(testdf, id.vars="color")

p <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x=variable, y=color, label=value, fill=as.factor(value))) + 
  geom_text(colour="black") +
  geom_tile(alpha=0.2)
p
```

You can change what variable the values are mapped to using `fill=`, and you can change the mapping using `scale_fill_manual(values=[a vector of values]`.

That said, I'd be curious to see a solution that produces an actual table, rather than a plot masquerading as a table. Possibly using Sweave and LaTeX tables?

[image]