# How to plot a table of values and corresponding colors in R? The dreaded heat map

Tags: r, plot, dplyr

I have a table of strings, known as 'ratings'. These ratings have corresponding colors. I'm trying to figure out how I could plot these in R as a simple gridded table with the color that corresponds to rating.

[image]
    Highly Effective = "Green"
    Generally Effective = "Orange"
    Marginally Effective = "Red"
    Ineffective = "Bright Red"

The table is put together by reading a ton of excel data files, collapsing on Unit (y) and across Category (x) and summarising on scores.

```
unit.state.wide <- df %>%
  group_by(BU, CC) %>% # BU = unit, CC = Category
  summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dcast(BU ~ CC, value.var = "avg") %>% 
  print()  # end chain
```

Looks like this

```
BU AUDIT CORC GOV PPS TMSC TRAIN
Unit1   2.0  0.0 2.0   4 1.50   2.5
Unit2   3.0  1.4 3.2   1 1.50   3.0
Unit3   2.5  2.4 2.8   3 2.75   2.5
```

This question differs from the duplicate marked in that I am not trying to translate a numeric to a color, rather, a string. None of the examples discuss mapping a string value to a color value. Does anyone know of a good way to map the string to a color?

Comment: I agree that a heatmap may be one approach to this  Have you tried any heatmap plotting code that failed for you?  `geom_tile` from *ggplot2* would be an option if you reshape your dataset prior to plotting, but there are other options.

Comment: There is a heatmap solution proposed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665994/4752675)

Comment: Actually,  I like another solution proposed in the same post.  use `plotrix::addtable2plot`.   Just follow the example on the help page.

Comment: For the plotrix one, I dont understand how I would pass it a range of values to evaluate to get the color.