# How to maintain original row names when binding rows from different data frames?

Tags: r, dplyr, rows

How can I preserve one of the grouping names when using dply::summarise? Or, is there a better way to preserve one of the group names? I am probably going about this rather inefficiently.

I have a data.frame (df) as such:

```
dput(head(df, n = 20))
structure(list(file_src = c("CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", 
"CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", 
"CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", 
"CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", 
"CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", "CBG_EFD.xlsx", 
"CBG_EFD.xlsx"), AU = c("CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", 
"CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", 
"CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD", "CBD"), BU = c("OAO", "Constr", "Retail", 
"OAO", "Constr", "Retail", "OAO", "Constr", "Retail", "OAO", 
"Constr", "Retail", "OAO", "Constr", "Retail", "OAO", "Constr", 
"Retail", "OAO", "Constr"), CC = c("AUDIT", "AUDIT", "AUDIT", 
"AUDIT", "AUDIT", "AUDIT", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", 
"CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", "CORC", 
"CORC"), CA_LVL = c("AUDIT01", "AUDIT01", "AUDIT01", "AUDIT02", 
"AUDIT02", "AUDIT02", "CORC01", "CORC01", "CORC01", "CORC02", 
"CORC02", "CORC02", "CORC03", "CORC03", "CORC03", "CORC04", "CORC04", 
"CORC04", "CORC05", "CORC05"), Score = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2)), .Names = c("file_src", 
"AU", "BU", "CC", "CA_LVL", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Defintions**
Where AU is a set of five (5) 'groups' and BU is a set of fifty-five (55) units all of which belong to one of the five AUs. Parent-child relationship. Score is a raw number 0-4. Control_Category is a variable of which there are six (string values).

Currently, my code is broken out such that the script performs two levels of grouping and aggregating of scores to give a simple average. I group first at the AU level to get simple averages across all of the units of a given group for their respective Categories (CC). In the end, I have five data.frames (cbg.au.stat.wide, cbd.au.stat.wide, etc). These dfs represent the average score for a given category across all units of a given group.

```
# Group1 assessment unit scores
cbg.au.stat.wide <- df %>%
  group_by(AU, CC) %>%
  filter(AU == "CBG") %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dcast(AU ~ CC, value.var = "avg") %>%
  print()  # end chain
```

Which produces:

```
cbg.au.stat.wide
   AU AUDIT     CORC GOV      PPS     TMSC    TRAIN
1 CBG     3 2.733333 2.2 2.666667 1.583333 2.666667
```

Later, all of the 'AU level' data frames are combined using dplyr::bind_rows

```
au.avg.scores <- bind_rows(
  bsa.au.stat.wide,bsg.au.stat.wide,cbd.au.stat.wide,
  cbg.au.stat.wide,wmg.au.stat.wide)

au.avg.scores
         AU    AUDIT     CORC      GOV      PPS     TMSC    TRAIN
1 BSA Admin 2.833333 2.000000 2.733333 2.000000 1.750000 2.333333
2       BSG 2.833333 0.000000 2.733333 2.000000 1.750000 2.333333
3       CBD 1.833333 2.533333 2.466667 2.000000 2.500000 2.166667
4       CBG 3.000000 2.733333 2.200000 2.666667 1.583333 2.666667
5       WMG 2.625000 1.816667 2.533333 2.166667 1.895833 2.375000
```

Then I perform a similar grouping and summarizing activity. Only this time instead of being at the AU level (parent) I do it at the BU level for each Category (CC). So, then for a given AU I know have a table of BU average scores across their Control Categories.

```
# Group1 business units by Control Category
cbg.bu.stat.wide <- df %>%
  group_by(BU, CC) %>%
  filter(AU == "CBG") %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dcast(BU ~ CC, value.var = "avg") %>%
  print() # end chain
```

Which produces:

```
                      BU AUDIT CORC GOV PPS TMSC TRAIN
1        Capital Markets     3  3.2 1.6   4 1.00     3
2                    EFD     4  2.6 1.6   3 1.75     3
3 Global Trade Solutions     3  2.4 3.4   1 2.00     2
4         Investigations     1   NA  NA  NA   NA    NA
```

What I think you'll notice here at the 'BU' level is that the 'AU' level has been dropped. Eventually, I'd like to combine all of these BUs into a big table that shows the BU and the AU from whence it originated

So that it would end up looking like this:

```
> bu.avg.scores
AU BU AUDIT CORC GOV PPS TMSC TRAIN
CBG Adherence   3.0  1.4 3.2   1 1.50   3.0
CBG CTR   2.0  2.8 2.0   4 1.50   2.5
CBG HRCU   3.5  1.8 3.0   1 2.25   1.5
CBD Investigations   2.0   NA  NA  NA   NA    NA
BSG ACH   2.0  0.0 2.0   4 1.50   2.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Here's an updated answer, based on the comment thread. We summarise by `AU` and `BU` separately and store the results in a list. We then show how to combine the summaries into a single data frame and to output the summary as a table.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Summarize by AU and (separately) by BU and store each summary in a list
dfs = list(AU = df %>% 
             group_by(AU, CC) %>% 
             summarise(avg=mean(Score, na.rm=TRUE)),
           BU = df %>% 
             group_by(BU, CC) %>% 
             summarise(avg=mean(Score, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Each summary is now stored in a separate list element. This keeps the two different levels of summary separate, but stored in one object so it's easy to process further.

```
dfs
```

> ```
> $AU
>      AU    CC      avg
> 1   CBD AUDIT 1.833333
> 2   CBD  CORC 2.428571
>
> $BU
>       BU    CC   avg
> 1 Constr AUDIT   2.0
> 2 Constr  CORC   2.8
> 3    OAO AUDIT   1.0
> 4    OAO  CORC   2.4
> 5 Retail AUDIT   2.5
> 6 Retail  CORC   2.0
> ```

If you want a single data frame, you could do this:

```
# Combine into a single table and spread
df.table = bind_rows(dfs, .id="Unit Level") %>% 
  replace(., is.na(.), "") %>%  # To avoid "NA" values when we "unite" below
  unite(Unit, AU, BU, sep="") %>% 
  spread(CC, avg)

df.table
```

> ```
>   `Unit Level`   Unit    AUDIT     CORC
> 1           AU    CBD 1.833333 2.428571
> 2           BU Constr 2.000000 2.800000
> 3           BU    OAO 1.000000 2.400000
> 4           BU Retail 2.500000 2.000000
> ```

If you're creating a report in `rmarkdown`, you can turn this into an output table. Here's an example where we remove repeated row identifiers:

````
```{r}
knitr::kable(df.table %>% 
               mutate(`Unit Level` = replace(`Unit Level`, duplicated(`Unit Level`), "")))
```
````

This is what the table looks like when output in a PDF file:

[image]

Or, if you want to add a midrule line to separate the `AU` and `BU` averages, you could do this:

````
```{r, results="asis"}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.include.rownames=FALSE, xtable.comment=FALSE)

print(xtable(df.table %>% 
               mutate(`Unit Level` = replace(`Unit Level`, duplicated(`Unit Level`), ""))),
             hline.after=c(-1,0,cumsum(table(df.table["Unit Level"]))))
```
````

[image]

### Original Answer

In the code below we first calculate average at the `AU` and `BU` level. Then we calculate the average at the `AU` level and use `bind_rows` to combine the two levels of averages. Then we can `spread` the resulting data frame to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Get averages at the AU-BU level
dfs = df %>%
  group_by(AU, BU, CC) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) 

dfs
```

> ```
>      AU     BU    CC     n   avg
> 1   CBD Constr AUDIT     2   2.0
> 2   CBD Constr  CORC     5   2.8
> 3   CBD    OAO AUDIT     2   1.0
> 4   CBD    OAO  CORC     5   2.4
> 5   CBD Retail AUDIT     2   2.5
> 6   CBD Retail  CORC     4   2.0
> ```

```
# Combine with averages at the AU level
dfs = bind_rows(dfs, 
                df %>%
                  group_by(AU, CC) %>%
                  summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                  mutate(BU = paste("All", AU,"BU")))

dfs
```

> ```
>      AU         BU    CC      avg
> 1   CBD     Constr AUDIT 2.000000
> 2   CBD     Constr  CORC 2.800000
> 3   CBD        OAO AUDIT 1.000000
> 4   CBD        OAO  CORC 2.400000
> 5   CBD     Retail AUDIT 2.500000
> 6   CBD     Retail  CORC 2.000000
> 7   CBD All CBD BU AUDIT 1.833333
> 8   CBD All CBD BU  CORC 2.428571
> ```

```
# Spread (does same thing as dcast, but using tidyr spread function)
dfs %>% spread(CC, avg)
```

> ```
>      AU         BU    AUDIT     CORC
> 1   CBD All CBD BU 1.833333 2.428571
> 2   CBD     Constr 2.000000 2.800000
> 3   CBD        OAO 1.000000 2.400000
> 4   CBD     Retail 2.500000 2.000000
> ```

This can be combined into a single chain:

```
dfs = df %>%
  group_by(AU, BU, CC) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    df %>%
      group_by(AU, CC) %>%
      summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(BU = paste("All", AU,"BU"))
  ) %>% 
  spread(CC, avg)
```

Comment: I need to present two results: category averages at the AU level (there are five of these) and category averages at the BU level (there are 55 of these overall). If what you have shown "All CBD" is the average at the AU level and the underlying rows are the averages at the BU level, then I think this fits!

Comment: When you say "Combine the two levels of averages". Do you mean stacking the AU level averages (average taken for each category across 55 BUs) on top of the BU level averages (average taken for a category for a specific BU)?

Comment: In this case, there are two sets of averages that I've stacked: (1) Average for each `AU` and (2) average for each combination of `AU` and `BU`. If you want the average for each `BU` across all `AU`, then instead of `group_by(AU, BU, CC)`, you would do `group_by(BU, CC)`. But then, since the averages are no longer hierarchical, you would also want to change how you set up the final table to make it clear what level each average came from. Let me know if that's what you are looking for and I can update my answer.

Comment: Yes. That is it. I need to present the AU averages, and then the BU averages separately. All of the code is here if you want to look: https://github.com/wfio/ctrl-score

Comment: Is this for output to a table in a spreadsheet or report, or are you planning to do further analysis in R on the resulting table? I ask because it's probably better to have two separate tables (maybe stored in a list) if you want to do further analysis, rather than combining them into a single table.

Comment: After these numeric scores are derived, there is another table created that translates the scores into their string representations. Once I have the table of string ratings, those get put into a spreadsheet for condition coloring and then ultimately the tables inserted into a report. I haven't yet figured out how to plot the table of rings with conditional colors :( I'd rather just do the entire report in R Markdown.

Comment: I love the knittr inclusion. Your answer is very interesting. However, I need the tables to be presented as I've included in the question. BUs and AUs on the vertical, Categories across the top as variables, and scores filling the intersections. Here's another post where I'm trying to figure out how to conditional color. It shows the a 'real life' table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849071/how-to-plot-a-table-of-values-and-corresponding-colors-in-r-the-dreaded-heat-ma

Comment: Yes, that's right. Keeping things in a list, whether multiple similar data frames or collections of related objects (like the list output of R modeling functions, such as `lm` or `glm`) makes it easier to do further analysis and processing and also keeps your workspace tidy, because you have one list rather than 10 or 20 or whatever separate objects to keep track of.

Comment: In the answer where you've indicated the script could keep everything in a data.frame the output of AU does not preserve the original AU. it just indicates what level it's from, AU vs BU. It would be smashing if I could preserve the original AU and BU.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you paste into your question an example of what the table would look like?

Comment: The example is the last table in my question. The table.df is fantastic except that the 'Unit Level' it specifies 'AU' or 'BU' and it should be the actual name of the 'AU'. This looks like it would have the unfortunate consequence of doing: Unit Level = BSA Admin, Unit = BSA Admin. We don't really care about having the all of the AU stats stacked on the BU. Unless it were hierarchical AU1 < BU1, BU2, BU3, AU2 < BU4, BU5, BU6, etc.

Comment: Well, you could do this: `df.table = bind_rows(dfs, .id="Unit Level") %>% spread(CC, avg)`. But then you'll have complementary missing values in the `AU` and `BU` columns. The `unite` step in my answer is what combines these two columns into a single `Unit` column. The `Unit Level` column is there to mark which level each `Unit` came from.